# Netbeans styles. Are there style profiles similar to Notepad++?

Tags: netbeans, style

Not long ago I started to use Ubuntu. When I was on Windows I used Notepad++. I was very surprised when I found that Notepad++ is only for Windows. So I installed Netbeans.

Netbeans is a powerful IDE and in general I like it, except default styles. Maybe are there style profiles (i.e. plugins or other forms)? It would be good if there is a style profile completely identical to Notepad++.

I will be very thankful if you would help me to find what I'm looking for.

Comment: Are you referring to the gui of Netbeans or what. Please explain "styles" a bit

Comment: Styles of editor (fonts, colors, etc.)

Comment: You can install Notepad++ using wine. I did it and worked perfectly.

Comment: I don't think, this question is off-topic on the site. Netbeans software natively run on Ubuntu and asking question about using a software in Ubuntu in on-topic as described in the [Faq](http://askubuntu.com/faq), in my opinion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know whether there is any style presets other than the default ones you can use, but you can definitely change the various fonts and there sizes, colors etc.

- Open netbeans and Go to *Tools* → *Options* from menu
- Select the *Fonts and Colors* tab. The window will look like below

  [image: Netbeans Fonts and Colors tab image]
- Then select the catagory and change fonts, size and colors as of your choice.

  **Please note** that, *foreground color* refers to the color of the text, which is may be of your interest. *Background color* is color behind those text.

Also, you may alternatively try some other style presets given by default by changing the value of the dropdown selection menu named *profile*.

Hope it will help.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I knew about this and I thought that there definitely should be ready Notepad++-like styles for Netbeans. So customizing would be my last option if I will not find any ready styles.

Answer (score 0):

You can download it from the following link:

[Notepad++ Theme for NetBeans 6.7.x](http://www.4shared.com/zip/m99rN_GH/Notepad_plusplus_Theme_for_Net.html?refurl=d1url)

1. Unzip file
2. From menu go Tools/Options then click on Import button in the shown dialogue browse the unzipped folder
3. From the shown tree check "Fonts & Colors" and click on OK button.
4. After restarting IDE again from menu goto Tools/Options select Fonts & Colors tab and from Profile combo box select "Notepad_plusplus"

have a nice time.

Comment: Note that this is a link to an unknown file on an anonymous file hosting site, if you download, unzip, and import it you do so completely at your own risk. It's not against forum rules, but generally [isn't a good idea](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3280/use-of-mediafire-or-anonymous-hosting-links-in-answers).

Comment: I tested it and there was not any problem. @Tom Brossman Do you have any suggestion for file sharing for me?

Comment: Cool, you are braver than I am. I never do this, I don't even add personal PPAs anymore. If this file you linked to is just text or code, can you copy the text and paste it into the answer? Don't know if that is possible without looking at it myself.

Comment: No i can not copy it here because it is a zip file that contain several xml file.

Comment: Okay, thanks anyway. The site hosting the file (4shared.com) is frequently used to distribute malware, partly because it's anonymous. That's the reason I posted the first comment. The page I linked to above explains the issues more clearly. You didn't do anything wrong, I just wanted to make the risks clear to new users. It's a good answer but for someone like me who will never download that file, I can't use it.